# BeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization is not called for DataSource bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shiro

I have spring boot app.

I have bean impl. `BeanPostProcessor` to create proxy for my `DataSource` bean. So when Application is initialized the `BeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization` is called for each bean:

```
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
   if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
       .... create proxy here
```

It used to work like a charm till an added another bean definition (org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.SessionDAO bean) which depends on `DataSource`. Now the DataSource bean will not pass the `postProcessAfterInitialization` method.

My guess is that the problem that the `DataSource` is initialized before `BeanPostProcessor`.

I added `@DependsOn("nameOfMyPostProcessorBean")` annotation to the `DataSource` definition, so the `BeanPostProcessor` is created before `DataSource`. So now the `BeanPostProcessor` is created before DataSource bean. (I verified that by adding breakpoints into bean's definitions). But it still doesn't work and `BeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization` is not called for `DataSource` bean.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Adding the `SessionDao` probably lead to the fact that the `DataSource` needs to be initialized very early on in the proces of starting the application. I suspect a warning/info message telling you so (something along the lines of *bean not eligible for post processing*).

Comment: Well, there is no such message in the log. But still, I don't understand why adding DependsOn didn't help.

Comment: Because it gets wired in a part of the startup that doesn't apply processors... It is basically setting up the processors. I suspect that apache Shiro has some post processor itself which uses the sessiondao making all the beans in that proces not eligible for processing.